# 400 Bad Request: The CSRF session token is missing in flask app

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, csrf-token

hello i try so many thing but i cant fix the problem i have a flak app live on a cpanel host
my code work compeltly fine on my local machine but when i try to deploy my app when users want to submit any flask form face this error : 400 Bad Request: The CSRF session token is missing.here is my main flask app:

```
from flask import Flask
from .extentions import db, ckeditor, mail, migrate, bootstrap, user_login_manager
from app.my_db_models import *
from app.config import Config
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.menu import MenuLink
from flask_gravatar import Gravatar
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

def create_app():
    application = Flask(__name__)
    application.config.from_object(Config)
    db.init_app(application)
    bootstrap.init_app(application)
    ckeditor.init_app(application)
    mail.init_app(application)
    migrate.init_app(application, db)
    return application


app = create_app()
api = Api(app)
mongo_client = PyMongo(app=app)
mongo_db = mongo_client.db

csrf = CSRFProtect(app)

from app.error_handeler import handle_exception
from app.admin_views.admin_page import CustomModelView, CustomView, UserView, MyHomeView, CafeView

user_login_manager.init_app(app=app)


@user_login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    user = User.query.get(user_id)
    if user:
        return user


from app.public_views import *
from app.private_views import *
from app.blog_views import *
from app.donate_view import donate
from app.admin_views.admin_view import clear_new_cafe, clear_subs, clear_users
from app.api import AllCountries, GetsingelCountry, main_doc

admin = Admin(app, index_view=MyHomeView(), template_mode='bootstrap4')
admin.add_view(UserView(User, db.session))
admin.add_view(CafeView(Cafe, db.session))
admin.add_link((MenuLink(name='logout', category='', url='/logout')))
admin.add_link((MenuLink(name='Home', category='', url='/')))
app.register_blueprint(public)
app.register_blueprint(private)
app.register_blueprint(weblog)
gravatar = Gravatar(app,
                    size=100,
                    rating='g',
                    default='retro',
                    force_default=False,
                    force_lower=False,
                    use_ssl=False,
                    base_url=None)
                    
csrf.exempt(public)
csrf.exempt(private)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

and this is my deployment config:

```
from os.path import join, dirname, realpath
from datetime import timedelta


class Config:
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+pymysql://favorit1_root:ug%qdnd4[maV@localhost/favorit1_database"
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    MONGO_URI = 'uri'
    FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH = 'cerulean'
    BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME = 'Admin'
    BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD = 'Tool789789@'
    JSON_AS_ASCII = True
    JSON_SORT_KEYS = True
    APPLICATION_ROOT = '/home'
    PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
    SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE = 35  # value less than backend’s timeout
    SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT = 7  # value less than backend’s timeout
    SQLALCHEMY_PRE_PING = True
    SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {'pool_size': 10,
                                 'pool_recycle': 60,
                                 'pool_pre_ping': True}

    IJSONFY_MIMETYPE = 'application/json'
    SECRET_KEY = "b'\xf1L\xdb5D\x96M\xe5\xd1\x9f\x16+\xf4%A\x1e\xb9\xafm\xb8g\x1ct\x0e'"
    MAIL_SERVER = "servert"
    MAIL_USERNAME = "email"
    MAIL_PASSWORD = "pass"
    MAIL_PORT = 465
    MAIL_DEBUG = False
    MAIL_USE_SSL = True
    MAIL_USE_TSL = False
    REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION = timedelta(weeks=4.0)
    UPLOADS_PATH_BLOG = join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), 'static/upload/blog/')
    UPLOADS_PATH_CAFE = join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), 'static/upload/cafe/')
    UPLOADS_PATH_USER = join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), 'static/upload/user/')
    NEWS_PATH = join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), 'static/news/')
```

and this is for exampel one of my routes:

```
@public.route('/user-sing-in', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@anonymous_only
def user_sing_in():
    counting = Counting()
    email_sender = EmailSender()
    user_manager = UserManager()
    form = SingUpForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(form.validate_on_submit())
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            auth = UserSingUpAuthentication(username=form.user_name.data,
                                            email=form.email.data)

            if auth.sing_up:
                user_manager.create_new_user(username=form.user_name.data,
                                             email=form.email.data,
                                             password=form.password.data,
                                             owner=False)

                login_user(user_manager.new_user, remember=True)
                email_sender.send_welcome_email()
                user_manager.create_admin_user(user_id=current_user.id)
                user_manager.active_user(user_id=current_user.id)
                counting.add_new_user(user=current_user)
                return redirect(url_for("public.index"))
            if not auth.sing_up:
                if auth.repeated_username:
                    flash(message="This username is already is use")
                elif auth.repeated_email:
                    flash(message="This email already in use")

    return render_template("public/user_singup.html",
                           user=current_user,
                           form=form,
                           title='Sing up')
```

and its my html form :

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
           
    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary px-4") }}           

                                    
 </form>
```

what is my problem and how can i fix this thank you so much